# longpress functionality doesnt work on a service?

Tags: android, service, android-activity, long-press

i tried a code to detect long press anywhere on the phone. this is how it is:

```
WindowManager wm;
View myview;
LayoutInflater li;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    System.out.println("\n=\n=\n=\n" + "oncreate service" + "\n=\n=\n=\n");

    li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            //WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_INPUT_METHOD |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,// | WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    System.out.println("\n=\n=\n=\n" + "lp " + params + "\n=\n=\n=\n");

    params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
    myview = li.inflate(R.layout.traslucent, null);
    System.out.println("\n=\n=\n=\n" + "View inflated" + "\n=\n=\n=\n");

    System.out.println("\n=\n=\n=\n" + "Layout inflator = " + li + "\nWindow manager = " + wm + "\nparams = " + params + "\nView = " + myview + "\n=\n=\n=\n");


    myview.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    System.out.println("\n=\n=\n=\n" + "On touch listener" + "\n=\n=\n=\n");

    wm.addView(myview, params);
    System.out.println("\n=\n=\n=\n" + "add view" + "\n=\n=\n=\n");


}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    wm.removeView(myview);
    myview=null;
}


@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LongPress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return false;
}
```

its not detecting the longpress but i tried a similar code for an activity and it worked just fine. this is the code:

public class testlongpress extends Activity implements OnLongClickListener, OnClickListener{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = li.inflate(R.layout.test_layout, null);
    v.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    setContentView(v);
}

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LongPress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return true;
    }
}
```

My question is WHY is it not working on activity but not on the service ?

Comment: A service has no UI, what is the user pressing?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Android Docs

> A Service is an application component that can perform long-running operations in the background and does not provide a user interface. Another application component can start a service and it will continue to run in the background even if the user switches to another application.

You can't have UI operation on Service, What ever view is displaying on screen is composed of Activity's UI not service.

For more information check the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) on service.

Comment: but my layout contains a cloud and that appears all the time even after the activity is over. doesnt that mean that my service is active and it's changing the UI. if this is not the way then is there a way to detect longpresses ?

Comment: Yes, write the same method in activity only.

Comment: @david See the code he has attached. It clearly uses windowmanager having flag of outside touch.

Comment: post full class, Show me what this class is extending.